# Run exe file on all files in a folder with 4 different options of operation

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I want to run an exe file on all files in a folder with 4 different options of operation. So each file produces 4 different outputs and I want all 4 outputs to have different names. 
Kindly be detailed in your response as I am not good at scripting. 
Regards!

OKay, here is example code I want to automate:

```
  exefile -p1 1 -p2 2 -i inputfile.etc -o inputfile_12.etc 
  exefile -p1 3 -p2 4 -i inputfile.etc -o inputfile_34.etc 
  exefile -p1 5 -p2 6 -i inputfile.etc -o inputfile_56.etc 
  exefile -p1 7 -p2 8 -i inputfile.etc -o inputfile_78.etc
```

The script should fetch all the file names from the folder, do these operation, and save the output with a modified name of the file.

Thanks!

Hi again, I need to improve it a bit. It should read all the files (two different extensions) in the folder and match the file names for similarity but of different extensions. Each file has a very similar file but with the other extension. So, two matched file names should be available in two variables that can passed on to the subsequent operation commands. Thanks!

Comment: Yes and your question is ???

Comment: We are all employed free to write code for Sheeda.

Comment: provide some code will help you get an answer

Comment: I have written the example code now!, thanks gsc-leticia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a num=1
for %%a in (C:\folder\*.*) do (
exefile -p1 1 -p2 2 -i %%a -o %%~na!num!%%~xa
set /a num+=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to give the names of the files to the operation explicitly and then save the output file returned from the exe file with a modified name (originalname_additionalInfo).

Comment: Thanks Bali, yes the output files should be named accordingly with respect to the kind of operation applied.

Comment: Hi again, I need to improve it a bit. It should read all the files (two different extensions) in the folder and match the file names for similarity but of different extensions. Each file has a very similar file but with the other extension. So, two matched file names should be available in two variables that can passed on to the subsequent operation commands. Thanks!

Comment: They would have to match exactly, like myfile.txt and myfile.exe, it can't really work just being similar. You can use `%%~na` in my answer instead of `%%a` to just get the filenames, and use `%%~xa` to get the extension, which should let you do what you want.